# Let button disappear when certain role is authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, roles

I have two different tables where two different kind of users are stored.

The first are Portalusers, the second are employees.

Now I have an overview page of all posts, where Portalusers should be able to use a filter button for a department.

Employees should be able to use it aswell, IF their role IS NOT "FBL".

So I tried it with this code:

```
@if(auth()->user()->Rolle != 'FBL')
                <div class="text-left mb-4 h-12">
                    <select name="abteilung" id="abteilung" class="h-full w-full flex justify-center bg-white bg-opacity-95 rounded focus:ring-2 border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base
                                outline-none text-gray-700 text-lg text-center leading-8">

                        <option selected="true" disabled="false">Abteilung</option>
                        @foreach($abteilungs as $abteilung)
                            <option value="{{ $abteilung->abteilung_name }}">{{ $abteilung->abteilung_name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        <option value="alle">Alle Abteilungen</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                @endif
```

But when no-one is authenticated, so a guest is using the page I get an error `Attempt to read property "Rolle" on null` - which makes sense since no-one is authenticated.

But I also tried putting this before the `@if`:

```
@auth('web')
   @auth('portal')
      @auth('guest')
```

I have two guards, the one is the default laravel guard and the second one is my custom `portal`guard for portal users.

Is there any way I can make this work, so that the button is available when guests, portal users and employees which don't have the 'Rolle = FBL`, but disappears when someone with this specific role is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if user is logged in before trying to access the user object.

To have it visible for guests and users with `Rolle` not as `FBL`, use this:

```
@if( ! auth()->check() || auth()->user()->Rolle != 'FBL')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#determining-if-the-current-user-is-authenticated

Comment: It works, the button is gone, but it is gone with every account and for guest as well

EDIT: it works when a user with a different Rolle is authenticated, but it doesn't work for guest and portal user

Comment: Nevermind! i had a typo, fuck me :D It works !!! Thank you ! :D

Comment: I updated the answer. Hopefully it's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your case, the best solution is:

1: Check if the user is logged in.

2: Check the role but instead of writing too much "ifs" I would do it like this (following your code)

```
//In your folder providers->AppServiceProvider.php -> method "boot"

    public function boot()
        {
            Blade::if('notfbl', function (User $user) { // you name it as you want I named it "notfbl", the parameter is the logged user
                return $user->id == auth()->user()->role_id != 1; // Here I assumed that the id of the FBL role is 1, you adjust it
            });
        }
```

// In your blade file you can use the "@notfbl($user)" in every part you need and also create more

```
        @auth // Everything inside "@auth" will be shown ONLY if the user is authenticated. If you want to do something for unauthenticated users you should write your html/code inside the "@guest @endguest" tags
            @notfbl($user) // It will be shown ONLY for users with role different to FBL
                <div class="text-left mb-4 h-12">
                    <select name="abteilung" id="abteilung" class="h-full w-full 
                       flex justify-center bg-white bg-opacity-95 rounded focus:ring-2 border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 text-lg text-center leading-8">
                        <option selected="true" disabled="false">Abteilung</option>
                            @foreach($abteilungs as $abteilung)
                                <option value="{{ $abteilung->abteilung_name }}">{{ $abteilung->abteilung_name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        <option value="alle">Alle Abteilungen</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            @endnotfbl
        @endauth
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested if statement i.e

// check if user is a guests, portal users or employees

```
if user == guest 

{

// write the code here for what guest should see

}

// so user is not guest

else 

{

// check if user is employee or portal user

    if user == employee

     {

     // write the code here for what employee should see

     }

     // user is not employee so user is portal user

     else

     {
    
      // write the code here for what portal use should see
     
     }
}
```